# Will my website get a dedicated IP when hosted with a Linode plan?

Tags: linode

I've always used shared hosting for small business websites. I'm considering trying more modern alternatives like Linode, and I wondered if those cloud hosting plans come with a dedicated IP for the website I plan to host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

To be more specific though, a "Linode" is a virtual machine (VM) from the company Linode. It's a server that you can use for whatever you want. The serve comes with an IPv4 address that you can use for whatever you want, such as a website.

Comment: Thanks very much Feliciano. It's much clearer in my mind now.